# How to send signal from Linux kernel space to user space in order to notify about an input hardware event

Tags: c, linux-kernel, signals, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

My kernel module code needs to send signal to a user land program, to transfer its execution to registered signal handler.

In fact, I have developed a C program for my embedded board which make LED turns on and off when I push BUTTON ( the input event ). On the other hand, I have just developed a simple Linux module with its basic functions ( OPEN, CLOSE, READ, WRITE ).

I just don't have any idea how to modify my principal program and my kernel module in order to arrive to my objective.

I share with you my user space program :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <sys/select.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <errno.h>

#include <linux/input.h>

#define BTN_FILE_PATH "/dev/input/event0"
#define LED_PATH "/sys/class/leds"

#define green "green"

void change_led_state(char *led_path, int led_value)
{
    char    lpath[64];
    FILE    *led_fd;

    strncpy(lpath, led_path, sizeof(lpath) - 1);
    lpath[sizeof(lpath) - 1] = '\0';

    led_fd = fopen(lpath, "w");

    if (led_fd == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "simplekey: unable to access led\n");
        return;
    }

    fprintf(led_fd, "%d\n", led_value);

    fclose(led_fd);
}

void reset_leds(void)
{

    change_led_state(LED_PATH "/" green "/brightness", 0);
}

int configure_leds(void)
{
    FILE    *r_fd;
    char    *none_str = "none";

    /* Configure leds for hand control */

    r_fd = fopen(LED_PATH "/" green "/trigger", "w");




    fprintf(r_fd, "%s\n", none_str);


    fclose(r_fd);


    /* Switch off leds */
    reset_leds();

    return 0;
}

void eval_keycode(int code)
{

    static int green_state = 0;

    switch (code) {
    case 260:
        printf("BTN left pressed\n");

        /* figure out green state */

        green_state = green_state ? 0 : 1;

        change_led_state(LED_PATH "/" green "/brightness", green_state);
        break;
    }
}


int main(void)
{
    int file;
    /* how many bytes were read */
    size_t  rb;
    int ret;
    int yalv;
    /* the events (up to 64 at once) */
    struct input_event  ev[64];
    char    *str = BTN_FILE_PATH;

    printf("Starting simplekey app\n");

    ret = configure_leds();
    if (ret < 0)
        exit(1);

    printf("File Path: %s\n", str);

    if((file = open(str, O_RDONLY)) < 0) {
        perror("simplekey: File can not open");
        exit(1);
    }

    for (;;) {
        /* Blocking read */
        rb= read(file, &ev, sizeof(ev));

        if (rb < (int) sizeof(struct input_event)) {
            perror("simplekey: short read");
            exit(1);
        }

        for (yalv = 0;
            yalv < (int) (rb / sizeof(struct input_event));
            yalv++) {
            if (ev[yalv].type == EV_KEY) {
                printf("%ld.%06ld ",
                    ev[yalv].time.tv_sec,
                    ev[yalv].time.tv_usec);
                printf("type %d code %d value %d\n",
                        ev[yalv].type,
                        ev[yalv].code, ev[yalv].value);

                /* Change state on button pressed */
                if (ev[yalv].value == 0)
                    eval_keycode(ev[yalv].code);
            }
        }
    }

    close(file);
```

And this is the basic kernel module :

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/device.h>  
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/uaccess.h>
#include <linux/input.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");      
MODULE_AUTHOR("Gaston");  
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("A simple Linux char driver"); 
MODULE_VERSION("0.1"); 


ssize_t exer_open(struct inode *pinode, struct file *pfile) {

    printk(KERN_INFO "Device has been opened\n");

    return 0;
}



ssize_t exer_read(struct file *pfile, char __user *buffer, size_t length, loff_t *offset) {

    return 0;
}



ssize_t exer_write(struct file *pfile, const char __user *buffer, size_t length, loff_t *offset) {

    return 0;

}   




ssize_t exer_close(struct inode *pinode, struct file *pfile) {

    printk(KERN_INFO "Device successfully closed\n");
    return 0;
}


struct file_operations exer_file_operations = { 
    .owner = THIS_MODULE,
    .open = exer_open,
    .read = exer_read,
    .write = exer_write,
    .release = exer_close,
};


int exer_simple_module_init(void) {

    printk(KERN_INFO "Initializing the LKM\n");
    register_chrdev(240, "Simple Char Drv", &exer_file_operations);
    return 0;
}


void exer_simple_module_exit(void) {

    unregister_chrdev(240, "Simple Char Drv");
}


module_init(exer_simple_module_init);
module_exit(exer_simple_module_exit);
```

I hope you will help me. Thank you!

Comment: Have you searched other questions on this topic? Googling for "linux kernel notify user space" finds several questions suggested using poll/epoll (e.g. [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24444670/event-notification-from-kernel-space-to-user-space)). [Another one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19877614/3440745) suggests to sending a signal.

Comment: First of all, you need to implement some code, that recognizes the button press. This can be a (kernel or userspace) thread that polls some port, or an interrupt handler. That depends on the hardware you use. After that, you can keep track of the processes , that have your char device opened and, if you really do not want to use polling, send signals (with `send_sig_info()` or similar) to those processes.

Comment: There is no reason to *"send signal from Linux kernel ... to notify about an input hardware event"*.   Userspace already gets notification when you read a `struct input_event`.  Did you notice that the button press is passed from the kernel to userspace as an "input event"?  So you want to send a redundant *"signal"* to indicate that there's an "input event" that needs to be read?  The blocking **read()** that your program already uses is all that you need to receive notification in the most timely and efficient manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will concentrate on sending a signal, since that is what you asked for, although sending signals to a process is quite brutal. It would be better to implement `poll` and `read` file operations so the user code can wait for events from the device and read them.

Anyway, for sending a signal to the processes that opened the device, the things you need are:

1. You need a `struct fasync_struct *` in the private data of your device:

   ```
   struct fasync_struct *pasync_queue;
   ```

   **It needs to be initialized to `NULL` by some means during initialization of your device private data. How you do that is up to you.**
2. You need a fasync file operation handler pointed to by the `fasync` member of your `struct file_operations`. The implementation of the fasync handler is very simple as it just needs to call `fasync_helper()` using supplied parameters and a pointer to your device's private `struct fasync_struct *`:

   ```
   static int exer_fasync(int fd, struct file *pfile, int mode)
   {
        // N.B. Change this code to use the pasync_queue member from your device private data.
        struct fasync_struct **fapp = &pasync_queue;
        return fasync_helper(fd, pfile, mode, fapp);
   }

   struct file_operations exer_file_operations = { 
        .owner = THIS_MODULE,
        .open = exer_open,
        .read = exer_read,
        .write = exer_write,
        .release = exer_close,
        .fasync = exer_fasync,
   };
   ```
3. Your device driver can send a `SIGIO` signal by calling `kill_fasync()` as follows:

   ```
        // N.B. Change this code to use the pasync_queue member from your device private data.
        struct fasync_struct **fapp = &pasync_queue;
        kill_fasync(fapp, SIGIO, POLL_IN);
   ```

   N.B. The last parameter (value `POLL_IN` in this case) affects the value of the `si_band` member of the `siginfo_t` that your application sees in its signal handler.
4. Your application needs to set a signal handler for the `SIGIO` signal. I recommend using`sigaction()` to set this up.
5. Your application needs to set the `O_ASYNC` flag when it opens the device file, or set it by calling `fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, O_ASYNC);` after opening the device file.